# Как при помощи ассемблерной вставки в си получить значение текущего времени

Tags: c, ассемблер, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned get_time_asm(void){
    unsigned hour, min, sec;
    __asm__  (
        "movl $0x02, %%eax\n\t"
        "int $0x1a\n\t"
        "movb %%ch, %0\n\t"
        "movb %%cl, %1\n\t"
        "movb %%dh, %2\n\t"
        :"=m"(hour), "=m"(min), "=m"(sec)

    );

    return hour*3600 + min*60 + sec;
}


int main(){
    unsigned current_time = get_time_asm(), temp, dt = 2;
    unsigned try_counter = 0;
    sleep(dt);
    temp = get_time_asm();
    while (temp != current_time + dt) {
        try_counter += 1;
        current_time = get_time_asm();
        sleep(dt);
        temp = get_time_asm();
    };
    printf("vremya sovpalo s %d popitki", try_counter);
    return 0;
}
```

При выполнении получаю ошибку сегментирования. Пожалуйста, подскажите как это исправить и где получить больше информации и примеров по ассемблерным вставкам.
До этого пользовался
 http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

"GCC Польное руководство".

Comment: Вряд ли вы эту программу под DOS пишете... А использовать вот так прерывания где-то в Windows - не получится.

Comment: Если не получится использовать вот так, то где посмотреть как их использовать?

Comment: В серьезных операционках для обращения к прерываниям требуются повышенные права, еще масса всяких фокусов... Честно говоря, я их сам не знаю толком :) Вобщем, я бы на вашем месте использовал ассемблер для других задач.

Comment: Лучше всего использовать например функцию `time` из заголовочного файла `time.h`, без ассемблерной вставки. Это будет универсальным решением.

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием использовал готовые решения) Но хозяин( Препод) - барин.

Answer (score 0):

На ассемблере, в отличии от Си, нет универсального метода, который бы работал в  любой ОС. Поэтому, нужно самому ввести некоторые допущения и ограничения.

Допустим, если мы хотим, чтобы функция работала в Linux x86, то нам поможет вот такая вставка:

```
mov eax, 13  ; код системного вызова sys_time
push eax
mov ebx, esp
int 0x80     ; вызов прерывания
pop eax      ; eax = число секунд с начала UNIX эпохи
```